# Is there a way of styling UITableViewCell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view and I am adding several cells to it based on my json.

So far the code for adding cells looks as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-90)
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: frame)
    self.tableView?.dataSource = self
    self.tableView?.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView!)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    }

    let user:JSON =  JSON(self.items[indexPath.row])

    cell!.textLabel?.text = user["description"].string

    var photoURL =  "/path/to/my/icon/google.png"

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: photoURL)
    {

        cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Besides the `description` in my json I have also `username` and `price`. So far - since I'm adding only `imageView` and `description`, 3 cells look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to style it so that each cell looks similar to this:

[image]

(`price` and `username` are grey here`)? How can I achieve this effect?

===EDIT:

this is how I populate my table:

I'm fetching data from rest webservice to json:

```
func getAllUsers() {
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getUsers { json in
        let results = json
        for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
            let user: AnyObject = JSON.object
            self.items.addObject(user)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

and I invoke this method in my `viewWillAppear` function

Comment: If you build UI in IB,just drag labels to your cell and add constraints to make them fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create the layout of the cell using a custom style. Place labels and imageView like you would anywhere else in storyborad.

[image]

2. You will need to create a UITableViewCell file. The one I used is named ExampleTableViewCell. Make note of the subclass.

[image]

3. Now connect your cell to the ExampleTableViewCell you just created.

[image]

4. Now we can make outlets from the labels and imageView of the cell into the ExampleTableViewCell. Control drag from each element into the ExampleTableViewCell.

[image]

5. The final step is to configure the cell using the cellForRowAtIndexPath func. Make note of the var cell. We now cast this to the ExampleTableViewCell. Once we do this we can use the outlets in the ExampleTableViewCell to set our labels and image. Make sure you set the resuseIdentifier for the cell in the storyboard. If you are unfamiliar with this leave a comment and I can add instructions for this.

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier") as! ExampleTableViewCell

       cell.imageDisplay.image = yourImage
       cell.descriptionLabel.text = yourDescription
       cell.priceLabel.text = yourPrice
       cell.usernameLabel.text = yourUsername

       return cell
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it's really clear written! One thing though - when I run my app, this line: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("...` causes error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I added a small edit to my question to show some more details that may affect this solution

Comment: Also, here are two small screenshots http://imgur.com/a/hLSiO - did I set up the resueseIdentifier properly?

Comment: It looks like you used the reuseIdentifier correctly on storyboard. Did you put "CELL" in the code for `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as! ExampleTableViewCell` ?

Comment: yes, I did, I will accept your answer as the most helpful one though, because now I believe it's related to some other issue. For that I started a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535791/swift-and-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value/ if you have some time I will be super grateful if you could take a look at it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can make your table use custom UITableViewCells and style them to your liking.

In a nutshell, you create a prototype cell in Storyboard that looks like the example you posted and connect it to a custom UITableViewCell class with the elements you created. At cellForRowInIndexPath you return your custom cell rather than regular UITableViewCells.

Check out this tutorial for details: http://shrikar.com/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/

Comment: Add a short summary of the link you provided. If the link breaks, the answer isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UITableViewCell. You can go to the TableView on your storyboard and go to one of the prototypes and set it's class to your custom class and it's style to Custom and then you can ctrl+click & drag outlets/actions to the UITableViewCell subclass the same way you would for a basic view controller.