# swift and unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have a class:

```
class ListOfEventsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

and it contains a function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as! SingleEventCell
```

and when I run it - it causes an error that says

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

[image]

but when I go to my story board I see:

[image]

and when I click `CELL` I see in its properties:

[image]

and also:

[image]

so the identifiers for `CELL` are set up, but I'm still getting this error.

What else can I do?

Comment: change your if cell = ...... to if let cell = .........

Comment: try dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath method

Comment: @sateesh I tried, but then when I run the app I see `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CELL - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'` Which is weird because - as you can see on my screenshots - `CELL` is put as identifier...

Comment: register a nib in your view did load method , this error is saying some thing like that

Comment: I see you selected an answer below. Did that solve your problem as I know in the other question this did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Storyboard select your prototype cell
2. <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to open the *Attribute Inspector*
3. Write `CELL` into the `Identifier` field.

Then try again ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I did at the very beginning :) just check the last screenshot in my original question - it's exactly the same as yours ;)

Comment: @user3766930: Ok, then please try to clean the whole project: Xcode > Product > Clean. Then reset the Simulator and try again.

Comment: This is what I am doing: http://imgur.com/a/vZl26 is that the wrong field in story board?

Comment: Unfortunately cleanup didn't help here, I must do something wrong but I have no idea what is the problem here...

Comment: @user3766930: As far as I can see you are doing everything right. Are you sure the `UITableView` defined in storyboard is the **SAME** `UITableView` you are using in code?

Comment: yes, apparently it was different object, I guess... I removed the uiviewcontroller and replaced it with uitableviewcontroller and now it works, thanks for all the clues!

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
```

For your problem.

Comment: you should register a class in before you make your cell in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a bigger hint? :) I'm not sure what should I do with that, sorry :(

Comment: If the cell is designed in a storyboard this is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SingleEventCell
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with that that says: `'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CELL - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: Did you click on the prototype cell in the storyboard and name it CELL?
For naming conventions, rename "CELL" > "Cell", in both the storyboard and aforementioned code